# How to proceed with MFA with Multi-Level situations?

Tags: yodlee

I'm having some difficulties implementing the MFA workflow with Yodlee. The workflow does not specify how to proceed with multi-level banks, for example, when a bank asks for a phone number to send an SMS with a temporary PIN.

```
{
    isMessageAvailable: true
    fieldInfo: {
        responseFieldType: "text"
        minimumLength: -1
        maximumLength: 25
        displayString: "Enter your Mobile Number or eMail ID where to send the temporary PIN"
    } -
    timeOutTime: 111750
    itemId: 0
    memSiteAccId: xxxxxxxx
    retry: false
}
```

In this situation, what do I have to do? Keep calling the getMFAResponseForSite every 2 seconds?

Also, in order to perform the putMFARequestForSite, which type should I use?

```
com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFATokenResponse
com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAQuesAnsResponse
com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAImageResponse
```

Comment: More information about this question: in this specific situation, I manage to create the putMFARequestForSite by using com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFATokenResponse. However it's not clear yet which option to choose, because addSiteAccount1 or getMFAResponseForSite do not provide enough information to correctly create the put requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are 3 types of MFA (to know about types of MFA refer [what-is-the-mfa-differences-spotted-in-this-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592125/what-is-the-mfa-differences-spotted-in-this-case)

To differentiate you can use the response of getMFAResponseForSite.

1. SECURITY_QUESTION - The response from getMFAResponseForSite looks like -

> fieldInfo":{
>         "questionAndAnswerValues":[
>           {

hence you need to use  `com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAQuesAnsResponse`

2. IMAGE - The response from getMFAResponseForSite looks like -

> fieldInfo":{  "responseFieldType":"text",
>         "imageFieldType":"image",
>    "image":[

hence you need to use `com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAImageResponse`

3. TOKEN_ID -  The response from getMFAResponseForSite looks like -

> fieldInfo":{     "responseFieldType":"text"

Since there will not be any indication of Q&A or Image hence you need to use   `com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFATokenResponse`

You can also check the various responses of MFA at [getMFAResponseForSite](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponseForSite) and [getMFAResponse](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getMFAResponse). The fieldInfo returned in both the methods will be same and hence can be used to identify the type of MFA.

Hence in case of multilevel MFA you will have to use any combination of the 3 listed MFA types.