# What is the MFA differences spotted in this case

Tags: yodlee

What is the difference when a site account is like this (PMPS, FMPA)?

```
    "mfaType": {
        "typeId": 5,
        "typeName": "MULTI_LEVEL"
    },
    "mfaCoverage": "PMPS",
```

Versus this:

```
    "mfaType": {
        "typeId": 4,
        "typeName": "SECURITY_QUESTION"
    },
    "mfaCoverage": "FMPA",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"mfaCoverage": "PMPS" is used for representing the financial institution sites which does not prompt MFA for all the users accessing the web site. This denotes that MFA will be prompted only for some users.`

`"mfaCoverage": "FMPA" is used for representing the financial institution sites which prompt MFA for all the users accessing the web site. This denotes that MFA will be prompted only for some users.`

But you should not be worried about the coverage , instead should focus on mfaType.typeName to identify which type of MFA the financial institution supports.

Here are the possible values and it's meaning -

- SECURITY_QUESTION - means the FI site has security question and answer as MFA.
- IMAGE  -  means FI site asks user to enter the value from Image captcha.
- TOKEN_ID  - means FI site asks user to enter the OTP(one time password) received either by email or message or have a RSA token to generate code.
- MUTLI_LEVEL - this MFA is combination of any two of the above MFA types.